# How To Render To Multiple Textures With OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, render-to-texture

This was my understanding of basic steps to rendering to multiple textures.

1) Bind the shader locations to render at

```
m_uihDiffuseMap = glGetUniformLocation( m_iShaderProgramHandle, "diffuseMap" );

if( m_uihDiffuseMap != -1 )
    glUniform1i( m_uihDiffuseMap, 0 );

m_uihNormalMap = glGetUniformLocation( m_iShaderProgramHandle, "normalMap" );

if( m_uihNormalMap != -1 )
    glUniform1i( m_uihNormalMap, 1 );
```

2) Bind to what you want to render to

```
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_uifboHandle );

//diffuse texture binding
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, m_uiTextureHandle1, 0);

//normal texture binding
                                   (or GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1)
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0+1, m_uiTextureHandle2, 0);
```

3) Clear the buffer & specify what buffers you want to draw to

```
glClearColor( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

GLenum buffers[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 };
glDrawBuffers(2, buffers);
```

4) Set your shader program for rendering

```
glUseProgram( m_uiShaderProgramHandle );
```

5) Pass variables to shader like our 2 different textures

```
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, uihDiffuseMap );

               //or(GL_TEXTURE1)
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0+1 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, uihNormalMap );
```

6) Do render call things

```
//Draw stuff
```

7) set things back to default in case you have other render procedures using other things

```
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );
glUseProgram( 0 );
```

------------------------------FRAGMENT SHADER-----------------------------------

In the fragment shader you have to output the 2 results like this right?

```
#version 330

in vec2 vTexCoordVary;

uniform sampler2D diffuseMap;
uniform sampler2D normalMap;

out vec4 fragColor[2];

void main( void )
{
    fragColor[0] = texture( diffuseMap, vTexCoordVary );
    fragColor[1] = texture( normalMap, vTexCoordVary );
};
```

I've double checked
  -My diffuse texture and normal texture are loaded fine. If I pass my normal texture as the texture to use as TEXTURE0 it will show up.
  -I get fragColor[0] just fine. When i show the fragColor[1] to the screen I got the same result as the first one. But i also hardcoded fragColor[1] to return solid grey inside the shader as a test case and it worked.

So my assumption is somehow when I pass my textures to the shader it assumes "normalMap" is "diffuseMap"? Its my only understanding to why I would get the same result in fragColor[0] and [1].

Comment: To clarify, you are drawing to different textures than the ones you are using in the shader?

Comment: I have 2 textures that are just textures being used for drawing onto a box.

the 2 results are suppose to
  1)texture with the box drawn with box texture 1 
  2)texture is the box being drawn with texture 2

Comment: I do not fully understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: 2 textures for a box
..(diffuse map, normal map)

2 textures to fill
  (result1, result2)

on the screen i display result1,
everything is good..
on the screen I display result2,
i get the same result as from result1.

Comment: Wanted result should be.. Result 1 should show the box in diffuse colors
Result 2 should show the box in the normal colors

Comment: Sound good so far. Did you validate the framebuffer and check glError after every API call?

Comment: ummmmmmm I think I will need some explaining for this.. I added more glError() checks and everything now works....... Which obviously would make no sense. But I've been debugging this mini project for like almost 2 hours and I rebuilt it a few times too. Didn't change any part of it. Now I go add glError() checks and its all good -_-.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as of now the information how your samplers map to texture slots is missing, causing both to refer to the diffuse map. Use `glUniform1i()` to bind the index of the correct texture to each uniform slot.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post that. I updated the information. It should be step 1 now. Thanks for noticing =]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like step 1 and step 4 are in the wrong order. This is in step 1:

```
if( m_uihDiffuseMap != -1 )
    glUniform1i( m_uihDiffuseMap, 0 );

if( m_uihNormalMap != -1 )
    glUniform1i( m_uihNormalMap, 1 );
```

and this in step 4:

```
glUseProgram( m_uiShaderProgramHandle );
```

`glUniform*()` calls apply to the currently active program. So `glUseProgram()` must be called **before** the `glUniform1i()` calls.

It might also be a good idea to specifically set the location of the `out` variable:

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragColor[2];
```

I don't think this is causing your problem, but I don't see anything in the spec saying that the linker assigns locations starting at 0 if they are not explicitly specified.

Comment: layout location placement is a openGL 4 thing. I'm using 3.3 just to give myself a small limitation.

also I think it might have been when i predefined those texture locations in the shader. I had a LinkProgram() call but I had forgotten to call glUseProgram right after. I have no idea why I assumed LinkProgram still had my program bound. So really it wasnt that 4 was wrong it was that I also needed that call before hand.

Comment: The layout location qualifiers are available in GLSL version 330. So did moving the `glUseProgram()` call earlier solve the problem?

Comment: I added the glUseProgram before the setting of those variables and things are looking good.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles upon here via a search engine like me, my problem with writing to multiple textures was a typo. My framebuffer initialization code looked like this:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &renderer.gbufferFboId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, renderer.gbufferFboId);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,  GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderer.gbufferDepthTexId, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderer.gbufferColorPositionId, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderer.gbufferColorColorId, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderer.gbufferColorNormalId, 0);
opengl::fbo_check_current_status();

const GLenum drawBuffers[]
{
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2
};
glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers);
```

Can you spot the error? It's a small typo in the `glDrawBuffer` call. It of course should be equivalent to the number of buffers:

```
glDrawBuffers(3, drawBuffers);
```